# streaming a webcam feed over rtsp using ffmpeg & ffserver to an android client

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, android-videoview, rtsp

I am trying to stream my webcam over rtsp and open the stream using android. 
I managed to get the first part working (rtsp stream) using ffserver and ffmpgeg. Here is my ffserver.conf file :

```
HTTPPort 8000
RTSPPort 8001
HTTPBindAddress 192.168.1.74
RTSPBindAddress 192.168.1.74
MaxClients 100
MaxBandwidth 10000
NoDefaults

<Feed witty.ffm>
   File /tmp/witty.ffm
   FileMaxSize 20M
</Feed>

<Stream witty.mov>
   Feed witty.ffm
   Format rtp
   VideoSize 640x480
   VideoQMin 1
   VideoQMax 20
   VideoFrameRate 30
   VideoBitRate 500
   AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
   VideoCodec libx264
   AVPresetVideo baseline
   NoAudio
</Stream>
```

ffserver :

```
ffserver -f -d ffserver.conf // luch the server
```

and then I use FFmpeg to open the webcam (Mac OS)

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "default" http://192.168.1.74:8000/witty.ffm
```

I can open the stream from VLC but on android using a videoView i am getting an error (1,-38) and an alert view saying "can't play this video".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Stream witty.mov>
```

**.mov (QuickTime)** is not among the Android supported video formats.

Use a supported format like 3GP etc.

You can find the [full list of supported formats here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Comment: it seems that `.mov` is not supported by android, after changing I am not getting the alert (can't paly this video") but a black screen and nothing inside.

Comment: Your encoding is probably wrong. Check the "Video Encoding Recommendations" section on the  linked page in the answer and the "Best Practices for Video on Android" [http://www.encoding.com/android/](http://www.encoding.com/android/).