# want to stream mobile camera using ffserver and ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, rtsp, ffserver

First i will tell you my requirement than i will tell you what i have done.

i am noob in media streaming i am learning and i am very confused about it.

basically i want to do following thing

1: mobile app will stream video on server through URL (which is on my laptop)
2: My laptop should run ffserver/ffmpeg which store video stream which is coming from mobile app and allow other client to watch it (here i am talking about VLC as client).

so this is my requirement.

i ham running ffserver on my laptop

my ff server config is like:

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0

RTSPPort 8091
RTSPBindAddress 0.0.0.0


MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -

#NoDaemon

<Feed feed1.ffm>
    File /tmp/feed1.ffm
    FileMaxSize 200K
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

# if you want to use mpegts format instead of flv
# then change "live.flv" to "live.ts"
# and also change "Format flv" to "Format mpegts"
<Stream live.flv>
    Format flv
    Feed feed1.ffm

    VideoCodec libx264
    VideoFrameRate 30
    VideoBitRate 512
    VideoSize 320x240
    AVOptionVideo crf 23
    AVOptionVideo preset medium
    # for more info on crf/preset options, type: x264 --help
    AVOptionVideo flags +global_header

    AudioCodec aac
    Strict -2
    AudioBitRate 128
    AudioChannels 2
    AudioSampleRate 44100
    AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
</Stream>

##################################################################
# Special streams
##################################################################
<Stream stat.html>
    Format status
    # Only allow local people to get the status
    ACL allow localhost
    ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Stream>

# Redirect index.html to the appropriate site
<Redirect index.html>
    URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
##################################################################
```

than i am adding following url to my mobile app to stream video.
rtsp://:8091/feed1.ffm
my mobile app start streaming my mobile developer team said that.
but i am not getting any log on ffserver, when i am stooping streaming the TEARDOWN request is comming

```
[TEARDOWN] "rtsp://192.168.1.57:8091/feed1.ffm RTSP/1.0" 200 7034
```

i have done this is so far, i dont know how to use ffmpeg with live streaming. please tell me some example for that.

i am not able to watch that live stream on VLC client. also tell me what URL should i enter in VLC for streaming i have tried almost every url combination.

and one more thing i want to do it with RTSP protocol.

i think this info will help you to understand my requirement.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245537/transfer-real-time-video-stream-to-server-using-android

Comment: Saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218581/streaming-a-webcam-feed-over-rtsp-using-ffmpeg-ffserver-to-an-android-client and also noticed that it looks like you are using flv container format - Android doesn't support that: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Comment: that protocols are for playing video on android, i dont want to play flv video on android. i want to take mobile video stream and want to play that video in flv or mp4 format on that VLC.